# Whitelabel Error Page - how to resolve this

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am trying to run a simple Spring boot application from 2 days but still unable to make it work. I checked all the related questions and blogs but still issue persist.

The main springboot App code

```
package com.smart;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.smart.*" })
public class SmartcontactmanagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmartcontactmanagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

the signup page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="base::layout(~{::section})">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                    <div class="my-card mt-2">

                        <div class="container text-center">
                            <img class="" style="width: 80px;" alt="" src="" th:src="@{/img/register.png}">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="text-center">Register Here !!</h1>

                        <form action="" th:action="@{do_register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

                            <!--    name field -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name_field">Your Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_field" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                    placeholder="Enter you name here" required th:value="${user.name}" name="name" />
                            </div>

                            <!--    email field -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email_field">Your Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_field" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                    placeholder="Enter you email here" required th:value="${user.email}" name="email" />
                            </div>

                            <!--    password field -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password_field">Your Password</label>
                                <input name="passWord" type="password" class="form-control" id="password_field"
                                    aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter you password here" required />
                            </div>

                            <!-- user about field -->

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter something about yourself"
                                    th:value="${user.about}" name="about"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <!-- terms and conditions -->

                            <div class="form-group form-check text-center">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="agreement" name="agreement" />
                                <label for="agreement">Accept terms and conditions</label>
                            </div>



                            <div class="container text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary text-white">Submit</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning text-white" type="reset">Reset</button>
                            </div>


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

the homecontroller page

```
package com.smart.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.smart.dao.UserRepository;
import com.smart.entities.User;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/about")
    public String about(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "About - Smart Contact Manager");
        return "about";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/signup")
    public String signup(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Register - Smart Contact Manager");
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "signup";
    }

//  this is Handler for register user

    @RequestMapping(value = "/do_register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            @RequestParam(value = "agreement", defaultValue = "false") boolean agreement, Model model) {

        System.out.println(agreement);
        System.out.println(user);
        return "signup";
    }

}
```

the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.smart</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartcontactmanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>smartcontactmanager</name>
    <description>First Spring boot project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the model class

```
package com.smart.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String passWord;
    private String role;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String about;

//  create a seperate table for mapping
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", passWord=" + passWord + ", role=" + role
                + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", imageUrl=" + imageUrl + ", about=" + about + ", contacts=" + contacts
                + "]";
    }

}
```

when i try to signin it is giving me a  :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jul 14 09:37:29 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

i have tried everything to solve this issue but still it doesnt work

Comment: Add your URL also issue with 404 not found better add the URL also.

Comment: And remove the Components scan you have correct package structure spring Boot will scan all components within sub packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`th:action="@{/do_register}"` write like this u forgot slash and remove @ComponentScan

Comment: thanks it worked. such silly mistakes i have done